# Can't run gauge spec but can run with Maven

Tags: maven, gauge

I'm writing a series of tests in Java with Selenium and Gauge, packaged with Maven. The specs are located in /specs, while the step implementations are located in /src/test/java.

The problem is that running the specs via Gauge returns the following error: *package org.openqa.selenium does not exist*. I've checked the pom file and all the necessary dependencies are there, hence why I can run it with `mvn test`, but Gauge appears to be missing them. I'm fairly new to Gauge so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's because the dependencies are built with Maven, and cannot be included without it. There might be other solutions but using Maven requires running with it as well.